# Prove there is sequence $(t_n)$ such that: i) $t_n →\infty $, ii)$ f'(t_n) =0$, and iii) $ \lim f(t_n) = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a bounded, differentiable function satisfying $\underset{ t \to \infty } \lim \ inf \ f(t) = 0$ and $\underset{ t→∞ } \lim \sup \ f(t) = 1$. Prove that there is a sequence $(t_n)^∞ _{n=1}$ such that: i) $t_n →\infty \ as \  n \to \infty$, ii)$ f'(t_n) =0$ for all $n \in N$, and iii) $ \underset{n \to \infty}\lim f(t_n) = 1$.

(i) Since, every bounded sequence in $R^k$ contains a convergent subsequence, there exists a sequence $(t_n)$ such that $t_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

(iii) Since $\underset{ t→∞ } \lim \sup \ f(t) = 1$, we have $ \underset{n \to \infty}\lim f(t_n) = 1$.

(ii) To show $ f'(t_n) =0$ , how to use  $\underset{ t \to \infty } \lim \ inf \ f(t) = 0$ and $\underset{ t→∞ } \lim \sup \ f(t) = 1$.

Comment: You are approaching this incorrectly.  Of course there is a sequence $t_n$ that satisfies $t_n\rightarrow\infty$ (for example $t_n=n$), but that does not mean $f(t_n)\rightarrow 1$ for all such, nor does it mean $f'(t_n)=0$ for all such.  You want to show existence of a sequence for which all three properties hold simultaneously. You will need some intuition, for example what kind of sequences can you take that ensure $f'(t_n)=0$ for all $n$?  What kind of point $x$ satisfies $f'(x)=0$?

Comment: Well try to observe that this function has infinitely many points of maxima as well as infinitely many points of minima and these points exceed beyond any bound. Thus we can take $t_n$ to be a sequence of maxima of $f$ such that $t_n\to\infty, f'(t_n) =0$ and then prove $f(t_n) \to 1$. If we choose the points of minima we get everything same except $f(t_n) \to 0$. As an example of such a function consider $f(x) =\sin^2x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded then $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$. You are given that $\liminf_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$ and $\limsup_{t\to\infty}f(t)=1$, so $f$ must be bouncing back and forth in some manner, think of oscillations. The assumption that $f$ is differentiable, and hence continuous, is important now because it tells us that as $f$ is oscillating, it does so continuously and so it must have infinitely many turning points.

Can you use this now to find $(t_{n})$?

Answer (score -1):

To get condition (ii), you are going to have to explicitely define the $t_n$ to satisfy this condition, it can't stem from a property about the limits.

Here is a way to do it: first define a sequence $s_n$ such that:

- $0<f(s_n)<1$
- $s_n$ is increasing
- $s_n \to \infty$
- $\forall n, \exists x \in ]s_n, s_{n+1}[:\ f(x) > \max\big(f(s_n), f(s_{n+1}),  1 - \frac{1}{n}\big)$

This can easily be constructed by induction: take any $s_1$ such that $0<f(s_1)<1$. Once you have $s_n$, since $f(s_n)<1$ and $\lim \sup f = 1$, there exists $x_0 > s_n+1$ such that $f(x_0) > f(s_n)$ and $f(x_0)>1-\frac{1}{n}$. And then since $\lim \inf f = 0$, you can choose $s_{n+1} > x_0$ such that $f(s_{n+1}) < f(x_0)$ and $f(s_{n+1}) < 1$. Simply note that $s_{n+1} > x_0 > s_n+1$, so $(s_n)$ is increasing and $s_n \to +\infty$. The fourth point is obvious by construction.

$ $

Once we have this sequence, just define $t_n = \mbox{argmax}_{t \in [s_n, s_{n+1}]} f(t)$. Using the fourth point, $t_n \in ]s_n, s_{n+1}[$,and since $f$ is differentiable, $f'(t_n) = 0$. Also, there exists $x_0 \in ]s_n, s_{n+1}[$ such that $f(x_0) > 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ so $f(t_n) \ge f(x_0) > 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Thus, $f(t_n) \to 1$.

Finally, you have $t_n \ge s_n$, so $t_n \to +\infty$.